# Turning whiskers into rectangles in boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have made a simple boxplot in R, and am trying to turn the whiskers into rectangles.  So the end result would be one rectangle (instead of a box with whiskers), with partitions at the 25th percentile, the median, and the 75th percentile.  Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), eg some numbers that you want to plot?

Comment: @gung I don't think that will help much, it's pretty clear what he wants. It's just probably a bit laborious.

Comment: That's a reasonable point, @SeñorO.

Comment: You will probably have to use `rect` and divide the quantiles yourself.

Comment: @gung maybe the best "reproducible example" he could provide is a custom drawing of the desired result?

Comment: That's part of what I had in mind, @SeñorO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# simulating dataset
set.seed(12)
d1 <- rnorm(100, sd=30)
d2 <- rnorm(100, sd=10)
d <- data.frame(value=c(d1,d2), condition=rep(c("A","B"),each=100))

# require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=condition, y=value, fill=condition)) + 
geom_crossbar(stat="summary", fun.y=quantile, fun.ymax=max, fun.ymin=min)
```

[image]